# What is a heterosexual term for “cruising”?

Tags: expressions, slang, connotation, gender-neutral

*Cruising*, the act of going out and about looking for a sexual partner, is generally only used in a gay context in the US.

What is a term with the same basic meaning but without the homosexual connotation?

**UPDATE:**

To whet your appetites, I’ve also thought about *tryst* or *rendezvous*, but they seem lacking.

Comment: Cruising now has the notation of riding around in your car.  You might be looking for girls... but aren't all guys.  It mainly means riding around and wouldn't have much of if any sexual connotation unless it was an inside joke.

Comment: All the terms related to this context are not limited to only one sexual orientation. You can describe with more than one word. For example: straight cruising.

Comment: @ermanen The reason I'm looking for a one word term is I'm trying to come up with a brand name for a service similar to grindr (a gay cruising app) but for heterosexual. "Straight Cruising" doesn't really sound too good while "Cruiser" or "Cruisr" does (unfortunately those domains are taken).

Comment: @tchrist, actually without going too much into it, it will be available to all sexualities. "Cruiser" would probably be fine in hindsight, or "Crawler" but I can't find any good variations of them with an open .com domain (including kruiser, krawler, krawlr, etc).

Comment: @tchrist, Well the original question stands. Doesn't necessarily matter why I'm looking for such a term does it? Fun discussions regardless.

Comment: The problem is that this is a question-and-answer site, not a fun-discussion site.

Comment: I suspect there's very little chance of you finding a short (six) letter domain name that means anything (even with the most corrupt spelling) with .com domain that's not taken. But _podger.me_ is available. _Podger_ isn't the same as 'looking for a _friend_' it's more like 'doing your new found _friend_'. NXDom.com can help you find domain names quickly.

Comment: The Four Lads would say *Standing on the corner, watching all the girls go by*

Comment: What make you think that if you are stumped for an association then all of your customers will instantly know it once someone on a website gives you one?  Names are tags, not definitions. Apple doesn't sell apples.  Defining your brand is a job for advertising, not the name of the company.

Comment: @frank, thanks for the NXDom.com tip. I was able to get "knobbr" which sounds sort of sexual but also brand-techy. Don't know if I love it but I'll keep looking at others.

Comment: @oldcat I agree that names don't have to be definition, but sometimes you know a good brand name when you hear it. I'm not opposed to something completely gibberish (tumblr, imgur come to mind). But just was looking for ideas. This community has been very helpful. Also, I think it was a fun question for the community.

Comment: @frank, I was able to snap up podgr.com so I'll add that to the list of potential choices. Thanks man.

Comment: Wow, a five letter domain that nearly means something, I wish I'd checked first. Good luck to your site.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm too old, but "cruising for girls" was what we did back in the day.

Comment: I'm looking for more of a term than a phrase though. If you say "cruising" generally it means looking for a gay sexual encounter (in the US at least). Perhaps getting some "strange" but that often means cheating on your partner. I'm talking about just going out to look for no strings attached sex.

Comment: That’s because *cruising* is what boys do, no matter what they’re after.

Comment: @user75341 _If you say "cruising" generally it means looking for a gay sexual encounter (in the US at least)._  That must be a (relatively) recent change in the meaning of cruising.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am sure some would say looking for a [*one-night stand*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-night_stand).  That is OK.

Others might say that you are looking for a *booty call.*  This is just wrong.  Booty call is for someone you already know and have been with.

My friends would usually just say, "I am *looking to hook (it) up* tonight."

But I think the perfect phrase for men is [*hunting beaver*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hunting%20beaver).  If gender neutrality is needed I would go with *hooking up*.

> A hookup culture is one that accepts and encourages casual sexual
>   encounters focused on physical pleasure without necessarily including
>   emotional bonding.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-night_stand) It is generally associated with Western late
>   adolescent behavior and, in particular, American college
>   culture.[2](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hunting%20beaver)[3][4] The term hookup has an ambiguous definition because
>   it can indicate kissing or any form of physical sexual activity
>   between sexual partners

Note: Will add *trolling* here but that word has a lot of definitions.  But one is scoping out for sex.

Comment: To be frank, I'm actually trying to come up with a name for a heterosexual service that would be somewhat similar to cruising. "Cruiser" sounds good, but the connotation is gay. "Hunting Beaver" is not a good brand name unfortunately.

Comment: Why isn't Hunting Beaver or Beaver Hunter not a good brand name?  You are what you are.  Hookup, Hook-it-up, The-Hook-Up...  Just saying if you want something that people associate with right away don't pick something ambiguous.  The big sites are pretty honest with their names, no matter how unfamily friendly they are.  Could also go with a variation of hunter.

Comment: I like the hunter variation idea. But it is very important that the name of the service appeals to women. Anything "hook" related sounds like hooking, which is very off putting to women for obvious reasons. "Beaver" also isn't a term that women are too fond of ;-)

Comment: [For the use–mention distinction, please use an *italic* face not a **bold** one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364)

Comment: Trolling is another word.  But that has so many meanings.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd hah I ran across that earlier in my word search. Yeah... that's definitely a no-go hah.

Comment: @tchrist - sorry trying to change bad habits.  Didn't know about the rule until last week.

Comment: The advantage of *hooking up* or *getting laid* is not just that it avoids both gender-bias and orientation-bias, it also avoids the predatory and sexist-pig connotations implicit in such rude vulgarisms as *hunting beaver*.

Comment: And thus does history repeats itself yet again, for *hookers* are nothing new to the English language.

Answer (score 2):

In Britain, one manifestation is *kerb crawling*, meaning the practice of driving at a very slow speed through a neighbourhood in one's vehicle and attempting to entice women into a sexual encounter, initially by addressing them through the vehicle's window.

Comment: I actually ran across that and I liked it but it sounds like it would be off-putting to women. I need something that can be used for both men and women going out and looking for no strings attached sex. The same goes for "dogging", it just sounds a bit gross. I am looking for a term that could be used as a brand name for a service similar to the grindr app but for heterosexuals. I am thinking about using some variation of "crawler" since that sounds good to me but all the good domain name variations are already taken. Thank you though.

Comment: This is good but not for girls.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - Agreed. Of course, that reflects the fact that it's not an activity that many women actively pursue.

Comment: @ErikKowal - Are you saying that women aren't looking for sex as much as men?  Haha they are just far more discreet.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - That wasn't what I was implying... I meant that they rarely *kerb-crawl* when they are on the pull -- in fact, I've never heard of such a case involving a female.

Answer (score 2):

Per Wikipedia, [*hooking up*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casual_sex) is:

> Casual sex or hooking up are certain types of human sexual activity
>   outside the context of a romantic relationship. The term is not always
>   used consistently: it may refer to extramarital sex, sex in a casual
>   relationship, one-time encounters, promiscuous sex, or sex in the
>   absence of emotional attachment or love, which can include
>   prostitution and swinging.

Comment: I already used that.

Comment: @ RyeɃreḁd, I was posting at the same time as you but you're faster on the draw -the curse of having a glass of red wine while typing

Comment: You posted 5 words 9 mins later...  wouldn't point it out if it were close.

Comment: Normally, I check for the term I intend to use with my search/find bar, and then post -I was distracted and failed to check twice; an impeccant action ;-)

Comment: The don’t call ’em *hookers* for nothin’, eh.

Answer (score 1):

A few you might consider

**Sniff** *I'm going out on the sniff*. From the way mammals tend to sniff each others genitals to check if they are ready for sex. Probably a more masculine action.

**Pull** *I'm out on the pull*. Presumably from the action of pulling someone toward you and saying in a romantic fashion *D'ya fancy a shag?* This works just as well for both sexes and I presume LBGT style encounters and has the added benefit of being a more flexible word *I was only in the club for 5 minutes and I'd pulled already* and also *That fat bird tried to pull me just then*

**Razzle** *I'm out on the razzle* or *I'm on the razz*. This is more descriptive of being on an adventure, usually alcohol fueled but can include the intention to end up having casual sex. This is all suitable for both sexes.

Comment: +1 for _pull_ (though I've met Americans before who'd never heard the term—they could learn, though!).

Answer (score 1):

One of the least flattering phrases I've heard used for this is *being on the prowl*. From [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+prowl):

> actively looking for a romantic or sexual partner

Given that [prowler](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prowler) (or prowlr) has its own illicit/predatory connotations, it's probably best to keep references to this phrase complete. One can do this by calling the app "On the Prowl" (which from the same link as *prowler* has a general definition of "actively looking for something") or keeping it only as a subtitle, like "*App Name*: an app for those *on the prowl*." Perhaps using another form like *prowling*, which to me sounds less criminal and more like something one would see in the wild, could work.

Comment: +1 This matches my idea of those older ladies looking for a young man : _cougars_. Assuming you can 'knock back' the advances of a 'Prowlr' you could rank them as a 'Growlr'.

Comment: I actually love prowlr, it sounds a bit dangerous and sexy but to me it doesn't come off as sleazy. However, the domain is taken. I might suggest you visit it, it's hilarious (and SFW).

Comment: @user75341 I thought about also editing in the related *chasr*, alluding to how sometimes romantic pursuit is called [the chase](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20chase). A reference to Li'l Abner's [Sadie Hawkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadie_Hawkins_dance#History) might work well there. I decided against suggesting it, since "chaser" is not as commonly associated with romance... and it does sound a little [alcohol-related](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chaser) too.

Comment: @user75341 Also "pickr-uppr" a play on "pick up," as in [pick up lines](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pick-up#pick-up_35). Unfortunately it sounds a lot like [fixer-upper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixer-upper) and also has a relationship to [alcohol](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/picker+upper).

Answer (score 0):

*Cruising* has been used in heterosexual context for at least the last 50 years [according to this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cruising+for+girls%2C+cruising+for+chicks&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccruising%20for%20girls%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccruising%20for%20chicks%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I agree with you that it is starting to be used in a heterosexual context, but given no context whatsoever other than the term "cruising" and sex, the majority of Americans will assume a gay connotation. The reason I need a term that has this desired meaning on its own without context is I'm looking for brand name ideas for a service similar to the app "grindr" but with straight connotations.

Comment: Not for anyone under 30ish,

Comment: This does not answer the question unfortunately. Also he did not mean that it is not used by heteros.

Answer (score 0):

[cruiser](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Cruise&searchmode=none) (n.)**

1670s, agent noun from cruise (v.), or, probably, borrowed from similar words in neighboring languages (such as Dutch kruiser, French croiseur), originally a warship built to cruise and protect commerce or chase hostile ships (but in 18c. often applied to privateers); **meaning "one who cruises for sex partners" is from 1903, in later use mostly of homosexuals;** as a boxing weight class, from 1920; meaning "police patrol car" is 1929, American English.**

The etymology of the word says that it was originally used for heterosexual search of partners.

I think that **to chat up** or **coming up to** are expression used when you want to approach a girl. I don't think that there is a synonym for *cruising* since it is a way of approaching typical of homosexuals. The dynamics between boys and girls are different.

Comment: As you say, the dynamics of boys and girls are different. *Cruising* is what boys do, no matter what the gender of their prey should happen to be. It is a term with gender-bias more than it is one with orientation-bias. A girl on the lookout for a one-night stand would seldom be said to be *cruising*, no matter what her own prey’s gender might be.